# Treeview in Nattable

Tags: java, treetable, nattable

I'm looking for a way to create a treeTable view in Nattable. I already have a NatTable implemented with filter, sorting, ...

But now I'm looking into a TreeTable like the TreeGridWithCheckBoxFieldsExample from the Nattable examples. The only requirement is that I do not change my datamodel for the tree.

I have two different objects Company and role. Every company does has all the roles. So in this situation I need a tree with all the companies as root object and all the roles beneath all the companies.

From the example it looks like I need to create a format class that implements the TreeList.Format but they are using the model to link the parent (I will not do this because it's a violation of the MVC principle.

Can someone get me on track to create a treetable view in NatTable?

After checking some example of Natable I got a working treeTable. But have only one problem left. The parent items are not correctly shown.

The treeFormat looks like:

```
public class TreeFormat implements TreeList.Format<PermissionViewModel> {

public TreeFormat() {
}

@Override
public Comparator getComparator(int depth) {    
    return new Comparator<PermissionViewModel>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(PermissionViewModel object1, PermissionViewModel object2) {

            return object1.getModuleName().compareTo(object2.getModuleName());

        }
    };
}

@Override
public void getPath(List<PermissionViewModel> path, PermissionViewModel element) {
     path.add(element);
     PermissionViewModel parent = element.getParent();
        while (parent != null) {
            path.add(parent);
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);  
}

@Override
public boolean allowsChildren(PermissionViewModel element) {
    return true;
}
```

The model that I use is a viewModel and is a one to one map to the normal model

```
public class PermissionViewModel implements Comparable {

    private PermissionViewModel parent;
    private ArrayList<PermissionViewModel> children = new ArrayList();

    private Integer permissionId;
    private String moduleName;
    private String permissionName;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean on;

    public PermissionViewModel(PermissionViewModel parent, Permission permission) {
        this.parent = parent;
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.addChild(this);
        }

        if(parent == null && permission != null)
        {
            this.permissionId = 0;
            this.moduleName = "";
            this.permissionName = permission.getModuleName();
            this.active = false;    
        }           
        else
        {
            this.permissionId = permission.getPermissionId();
            this.moduleName = permission.getModuleName();
            this.permissionName = permission.getPermissionName();
            this.active = permission.isActive();
        }
    }

    public PermissionViewModel getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void addChild(PermissionViewModel child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public List getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public PermissionViewModel getSelf() {
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        if (this.children.size() == 0) {
            return this.on;
        } else {
            return getCheckBoxState() == CheckBoxStateEnum.CHECKED;
        }
    }

    public void setOn(boolean on) {
        if (this.children.size() == 0) {
            this.on = on;
        } else {
            for (PermissionViewModel child : this.children) {
                child.setOn(on);
            }
        }
    }


    public CheckBoxStateEnum getCheckBoxState() {
        if (this.children.size() == 0) {
            return this.on ? CheckBoxStateEnum.CHECKED
                    : CheckBoxStateEnum.UNCHECKED;
        } else {
            boolean atLeastOneChildChecked = false;
            boolean atLeastOneChildUnchecked = false;

            for (PermissionViewModel child : this.children) {
                CheckBoxStateEnum childCheckBoxState = child.getCheckBoxState();
                switch (childCheckBoxState) {
                    case CHECKED:
                        atLeastOneChildChecked = true;
                        break;
                    case SEMICHECKED:
                        return CheckBoxStateEnum.SEMICHECKED;
                    case UNCHECKED:
                        atLeastOneChildUnchecked = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (atLeastOneChildChecked) {
                if (atLeastOneChildUnchecked) {
                    return CheckBoxStateEnum.SEMICHECKED;
                } else {
                    return CheckBoxStateEnum.CHECKED;
                }
            } else {
                return CheckBoxStateEnum.UNCHECKED;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Integer getPermissionId() {
        return permissionId;
    }

    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public String getPermissionName() {
        return permissionName;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

}
```

Putting data in the tree table will be done with following source:

```
ArrayList<PermissionViewModel> permissionViewModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String previousModule = "";
    PermissionViewModel currentParent = null;

    for (Permission element : repo.getAllData()) {

        if(!previousModule.equals(element.getModuleName()))
        {
            previousModule = element.getModuleName();

            currentParent = new PermissionViewModel(null, element);
            permissionViewModelsList.add(currentParent);

            permissionViewModelsList.add(new PermissionViewModel(currentParent, element));
        }
        else
        {
            permissionViewModelsList.add(new PermissionViewModel(currentParent, element));
        }

    }
    Collections.reverse(permissionViewModelsList);


    permissionTable.setItems(permissionViewModelsList);
    permissionTable.refresh(true);
```

But when I look at the table the root elements are viewed but the childeren of the root elements are wrong. I viewed the list of elements and there I can't find any issues. Can someone find the issue that I have?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your concerns regarding the TreeList.Format and MVC. NatTable is the view and TreeList.Format is part of it. It needs to show something related to the model. Therefore I think it is perfectly fine that the TreeList.Format as part of the view relies on the model to build the tree structure. So what are your concerns in detail? And how do you want to build a tree structure from your data model without getting information from the model?

Comment: It can be fine in some situations. But in my situation the Roles do not need to know anything about his parent (Company). Otherwise I need to create the same role for every company (1 role exists in all companies).

Comment: Then you need to transform your data model into a view model. NatTable operates on lists. And the transformation to a tree is done based on a list. If that list doesn't contain all companies and all roles related to all companies it is not possible to show such a structure.

Comment: With transform I mean, create a view model out of your data model.

Comment: I created a viewModel for that specific datamodel. But I have now an other problem. Added some more data in the question itself.

Comment: Your comparator is wrong. It doesn't take the tree structure into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to order of the columns. I placed the "Module Name" before the "Name" column. And the parent module name has been placed in the module name column. This fixed my problem.

The issue in this case was that the comperator that I used is not working on mixed data in the same fields. Tnx to Dirk Fauth I found it.